# Working with Multiple Forms C++

Tags: c++, winforms

I am currently developing a project that involves using two forms. The first form has button which opens the second form. The second form has a textbox and a button. When the button is clicked a particular result shows in the textbox. The issue is that when the second form is closed, the information in the textbox is 'forgotten'. How do I make the textbox keep its values even though the second form is closed?

The code for the button in the second form is shown below:

```
 int result = Convert::ToInt32(time1ComboBox->Text) * 200;
 parkTextBox1->Text = result.ToString();
 statusTextBox1->Text = "Occupied";
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have a variable that holds the result shown in the textbox, then set the text in the textbox to that variable when the 2nd form is shown again. `String text = result.ToString(); parkTextBox1->Text = text;`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling function to display the result not storing it any where try to use 
global variables or this

```
String S = "Occupied"
statusTextBox1->Text = S ;
```

Your result will be saved there or you should give more info on problem